# create percentage of subtotal using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm handling my data now. 
I have a problem.
Here are the my data and code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

complete_file = r'D:\handling data\question5.csv'
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(complete_file))

complete_data = pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(complete_file),sep=',', encoding='ANSI' )

complete_data.head()
```

[image]

```
complete_data = complete_data.groupby(['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD','SVC_INDUTY_CD' ]).sum().reset_index()
print(complete_data.head())
```

[image]

```
complete_data = complete_data.pivot_table(index=['STDR_YM_CD', 'SVC_INDUTY_CD'],
                                      values=['STOR_CO'] , columns='TRDAR_CD')
complete_data.head()
```

[image]

Here is my desired output

[image]

you can download my file from
http://blog.naver.com/khm2963/221085880259.

Sorry for saying that There are two step for getting file.
First, you can see the page if you click the link
[image]
and you should click the button,which is surrounded by red line, as you can see in the picture.
second, Small box will be popped up If you followed the first step 
 [image]

and click the button which is surrounded by red line
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found it. The code is 
`complete_data.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())`
[image]